# Neo4j I can not search the node by the property which with blank

Tags: neo4j

I create a node with a property with black
like this (n:x {name:"XXX YYY"})

when i search the node like this
match (n:x) where n.name="XXX YYY" return n

but it return nothing

anyone who got this problem?

Comment: Please add some detail to the question. Some code samples for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem 
when I enter to the browser,the line is too long,so the browser cut it to multiple lines. It cut the proprety string like this (n:x {name = "XXX 
YYY"}) so it add a '\n' to the string